# Issue on Closing All Collapse But First One in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/vq11wVObyL) and let me know how I can close all collapse BUT the first one in Bootstrap 3?

```
$('.closeall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.closeall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in').not($('.panel-collapse:first'))
    .collapse('hide');
});
```

It excludes the first .panel-collapse

Comment: Hi artm, this is working when collapse one is already open but when the other collapse are open it is not doing the job

Comment: @Suffii It seems to be working: http://www.bootply.com/iHyqmQuYwA If 2nd/3rd tab is open it collapses it. What's the expected behaviour?